# two version of Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

Further, I noticed that my site is loading two version of jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nyimexec.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.8.21"></script>
```

I have disabled most my plugins, except some menu navigator, and cannot identify where the jquery from google cdn is located. Which plugin if any? or in which file?

Can you help me

- idenfity where it is coming from (even general guide of where to look, or how to search)
- how to resolve that, essentially how to delete the jquery from google cdn.

I've been reading about a non-conflict mode but, don't know where to add the no conflict command when i cannot locate the jquery google cdn.

I am asking because I have a feeling it is causing my tabs not to work.
here is a page with the tabs not working http://goo.gl/umIYu

-- I realized that the first script is not same as second. However, Jquery ui from google cdn is in conflict with jqueryui used by my theme (don't know how to locate that and paste here)

Comment: `Ctrl+F` in your IDE is a good place to start.  Stick to one version of jQuery.  Otherwise, you're loading a lot of stuff you're not using.

Comment: One line is loading jQuery, the other is loading jQueryUI.  Two different libraries.

Comment: @brad where can I find IDE? the cpanel?
as a newbie I'm not familiar with all the acronyms, please be more specific.
I'd love it if there is a way to search contents of all files to locate that script

Comment: @jkal, Use whatever you are editing your code with.  I don't know a code editor that doesn't have a find-in-files function.  Also, Eric brings up a good point.  jQuery UI is not jQuery.  Are you sure you have two versions of jQuery running?  Just don't use two of them.

Comment: @brad, Okay so I found that the jquery ui from google cdn comes from the plugin. 
The other jquery ui, i think comes from the theme.

the issue is that the plugin doesn't work and I cannot figure out how to resolve it.
I am not sure if the jquery ui libraries are in conflict, or if it is another issue.

it was working when I first installed the plugin, but stopped on its own. (perhaps after installing W3 Total cache, but I disabled/ deleted that and the tabs did not fix.

please help.

Answer (score 5):

Though there is no problem in your scripts but you still may want to try this

```
var k=jQuery.noConflict();
```

and replace the $ with k in the new JS you  are writing like this

```
j(document).ready(function(){
     alert('hey I am not conflicting with any other jquery script');
});
```

**EDIT**

Add the `var k=jQuery.noConflict();` on the top of your javascript and replace all your $ in your JS with j.. j is nothing but a new jQuery object which is created by us and performs all functions that are performed by $ but does not conflict with any other jQuery file on the page..

**Example:**
If you have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#selector').click(function(){
          alert('Hi');
     });
});
```

it should be written like

```
j(document).ready(function(){
     j('#selector').click(function(){
          alert('Hi');
     });
});
```

after using the noConflict..

**Edit-2:**

**One of the other possible reason for your tabs not working can be the older version of jquery you are using**

You are using a higher version of jQuery UI and a lower version of jQuery, Which can be a possible reason..
Try replacing the follwing scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nyimexec.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.8.21"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks for your tip. Where should I add this?
I mean which file, or just the specific pages.
I am very new to jquery, or js for that matter.

please try and give me more detail

Answer (score 1):

You should list the versions from largest to smallest.

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.0/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.0.1/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.2.1/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.3.0/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.3.0'></script>
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

The two libraries are not same. One is the jQuery and other is the jQueryUI library which can be used together without any problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand. someone pointed this out to me in another forum, but then they stopped answering for days.
If you go to my page, can you see if there is two versions of jquery. and if so how to resolve that?